# IOS: what is native "Facebook Login SDK for iOS"?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on ios application where I have to implement facebook publish/share feature. what I have done for sharing is

1: if user is not logged in, I am checking with this

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded||FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
    //NSLog(@"Open");
    //Set already opened session to FBSession
    [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];
    //if user logged in already, perform sharing on fb
    [self sharePostOnFb];
}else{
    //if user is not logged in
    [self openFbLogin];
}
-(void)openFbLogin
{
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"publish_actions"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

    // Retrieve the app delegate
    //AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
    //[appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    if (state  == FBSessionStateOpen) {
        NSLog(@"opened");
        [self sharePostOnFb];
    }
}];
}

-(void)sharePostOnFb
{
NSString *strBznsName = [[[Global sharedInstance]getBznsInfo] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *strUserReceive = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ received %@.",[[[Global sharedInstance]getUserData] objectForKey:@"firstname"],[[[Global sharedInstance]getUserData] objectForKey:@"lastname"],dataStampDeal.strDealTerms];
NSString *urlLogoBkString= @URL_BZNSImgPath;
NSURL *urlLogoBkImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urlLogoBkString,[[[Global sharedInstance]getBznsInfo] objectForKey:@"logo" ]]];
NSString *StrUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlLogoBkImage];
// Put together the dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               strBznsName, @"name",
                               @"Powered By Anyloyalty", @"caption",
                               strUserReceive, @"description",
                               StrUrl, @"picture",
                               nil];
// Make the request
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                              NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

                              strFbPostId = [result valueForKey:@"id"];
                              NSLog(@"post id: %@", strFbPostId);
                              //[self WebServiceHandler:NO];
                              //[appDelegate startanimation];

                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                              NSLog(@"%@", error.description );

                              NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"]
                                                                 objectForKey:@"body"]
                                                                objectForKey:@"error"];
                               //NSLog(@"%@", errorInformation );
                              //__block NSString *alertText = @"Your action will not be published to Facebook.";
                              __block NSString *alertText = [errorInformation valueForKey:@"message"];
                              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"
                                                          message:alertText
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                          }
                      }];
}
```

facebook login `(-(void)openFbLogin())` is opening web dialog. After successfully logged in. I am sharing post `( -(void)sharePostOnFb())` on fb and I am getting error

"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

For publishing/sharing I have to get approval for "publish_actions" permission from FB. I have submitted my application to FB app developer center. I am getting this message.

"Your app must not use a Facebook Web Dialog. **Utilize our native Facebook Login SDK for iOS**, so that users do not need to login twice."

so Now I want to "what is native Facebook Login SDK for iOS"? and how can I integrate that with my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native Facebook login is nothing but using the iOS FB framework and create login using that. It is clearly mentioned on the developers.facebook.com how to login using there framework. You can also see the samples provided by them for login.

What this actually does is that , it check if the user has a Facebook application installed in the device and is user logged in to the Facebook app. If user is already logged in then user won't be asked to log in again. If user isn't logged in then they will be redirected to safari where they will have to log in to FB.

Its quite simple to integrate. Its well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook clearly says,

All iOS and Android apps should use their SDK's for iOS and Android for requesting permissions. Other apps should use their JavaScript for requesting permissions wherever possible.

Native applications on iOS and Android especially should use their SDK flows as they are optimized and work robustly across various types of devices without any manual adjustment.

In particular, their native SDKs let people who are already logged in to their Facebook app grant permissions without having to log in to their Facebook accounts again. This will result in far better conversion than not using our SDK and rendering our login dialogs inside web views embedded within your native app since the web view will not have any Facebook session data initially and will require people to login to their Facebook account.

**Please note:** if you are using Apple's Social framework, you may continue to do so, but ensure that if the user is not using the iOS integration, that your app falls back to the Facebook SDK for iOS. This can create more work than necessary, though, so we highly recommend using their SDK instead.

Here are the SDK implementation details:[**Facebook Login SDK for iOS**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1)